# Alternative to IN (SELECT...)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm fairly new to SQL so I'm doing this CS50 problem set. I found a solution that uses a WHERE ... IN (SELECT...) clause, but it seems quite slow and inefficient to me. Is there a better way to do it?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT name from "people"
INNER JOIN "stars" ON people.id = stars.person_id
WHERE
  stars.movie_id IN(
    SELECT movie_id from "stars"
    INNER JOIN "people" ON stars.person_id = people.id
    WHERE people.name = "Kevin Bacon" and people.birth = 1958
  )
EXCEPT
  SELECT name from "people"
  WHERE name = "Kevin Bacon" and birth = 1958;
```

The goal is to retrieve all actors that starred with Kevin Bacon (except Bacon himself).

The database looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
                    id INTEGER,
                    title TEXT NOT NULL,
                    year NUMERIC,
                    PRIMARY KEY(id)
                );
CREATE TABLE stars (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE directors (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE ratings (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                rating REAL NOT NULL,
                votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE people (
                id INTEGER,
                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                birth NUMERIC,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
```

Comment: No need for the EXCEPT. You can filter out Kevin Bacon in the WHERE clause.

Comment: There is no EXCEPT in MySql. Tag the database that you use.

Comment: It's not the most efficient way for this query, but I recommend looking into a recursive CTE, because the CTE will then let you answer the question "How many degrees to Kevin Bacon?"

Comment: @jarlh thanks but my question is more about the in (select) part. I put the except clause so that it's unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with joins.
Join 2 copies of `people` and 2 copies of `stars`.
The 1st copy of each table will be used to return the names of the actors that you want in the results and the 2nd copy of each table will be used to return all the movies with `'Kevin Bacon'`:

```
SELECT p1.name 
from people p1
INNER JOIN stars s1 ON s1.person_id = p1.id
INNER JOIN stars s2 ON s2.movie_id = s1.movie_id
INNER JOIN people p2 ON p2.id = s2.person_id AND p2.id <> p1.id
WHERE p2.name = 'Kevin Bacon' AND p2.birth = 1958
```

Maybe an actor starred in more than 1 movies with `'Kevin Bacon'`, so it would be better to use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.name 
.......................
```